# Pass a C pointer inside a Fortran77 subroutine

Tags: c, pointers, fortran, fortran77

The software I am currently working on uses both languages, C and Fortran77. The .f subroutines does the mathematical part, while the C routines manages the general behavior of the software.

My problem is the following. Let's say I have one C routine routine.c, and two Fortran subroutines sub1.f and sub2.f .

routine.c calls sub1.f which than calls sub2.f :

```
 ... ->  routine.c  ->  sub1.f  ->  sub2.f
```

My header file (Header.h) is define as follows

```
void routine(ITG *int1, ITG *int2, char *char)  
void FORTRAN(sub1(ITG *int1, ITG *int2, char *char))  
void FORTRAN(sub2(ITG *int1, ITG *int2, char *char))
```

(all the vairables are arrays)

Now here is the thing : if I write in sub1.f

```
write(*,*) 'int1(1) =', int1(1)
```

I actually get the first value of the array (corresponding to int1(0) in C)
But the same command line in sub2.f does not give me anything back, and I don't understand why.

Comment: it would probably help if you tell us what compilers you are using?

Comment: I use ifort for the Fortran code and icc for the C code (version 13.1)

Comment: what does "does not give anything back" mean? zero? value didn't change? Crash? As far as I can see, you do everything just right.

Comment: Int1 and int2 return 0 and char returns <nul> <nul>...

Comment: Hmm. Could you show how you define the arrays on the C side and how you call sub1 and sub2?

Comment: The meaning of the symbol `int1` in the Fortran source of *both* subroutines is a function of the their Fortran source.  It has nothing to do with the declarations in your C header file.  Furthermore, if symbol `int1` represents one of `sub2()`'s parameters in that suboutine's Fortran source, then its value is a function of how that subroutine is called, apparently by subroutine `sub1`.  You haven't given us any of the key information (Fortran code) we would need to answer the question.

Comment: if `sub2` is only called by `sub1` then it doesn't even need to appear in "header.h"

Comment: @agentp Indeed, but we do this to have a file storing all the functions. I find it very hepful not to have to open every function to know which argument they Need.

Comment: @mfro The array in C is created by calling a couple more Fortran function that will analyse and store data coming for a datafile

Comment: @JohnBollinger The Fortran code is rather light, but it would look like this : 
`if (char(4:5).eq.'42') then`
`int3 = 4`
`elsif(char(4:4).eq.'5') then` 
`int3 = 7`
`else`
`int3 = 2`
`endif`   
(Regarless of the number of spaces I put behind, I somehow cannot insert a linebreak, sorry ....)

Comment: I just stored the values of int1, int2 and char in others variables, and it seems to work. The code is a litte bit less clear but I'll take it for the time being. Thank you for your time !

Comment: @Extan, the additional code you presented in your comment has nothing to do with the problem you described, and certainly isn't what I asked about.  I'm glad you have resolved your issue, though.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Well it has, this same code would give me in sub1() the correct values, whereas in sub2(), int3 will always be equal to 0 (Default value), meaning that char is not transmitted to sub2(), and gets "stuck" in sub1(). It is the same for int1 and int2

Comment: @Extan, you're not getting it.  You haven't presented *anything* that gives me any reason to think that any variable in `sub2()` should have a value equal to that of a variable having the same name in `sub1()`, or that a variable in either scope should have a value related to a variable having the same name in your C source.  That doesn't mean there isn't such a correspondence in one case or the other, but you haven't given us a basis from which we could explain your observations.

Answer (score 1):

Please post all of your code so that it can be tested.  I have no idea what type ITG is or what Fortran integer size you are compiling for.  It's effectively impossible to debug your issue without more code of the code.

Passing character types between C and Fortran 77 is nontrivial.  Because Fortran does not use null-terminated strings, there is a hidden argument for the string length.  Your linker doesn't notice and it probably isn't the issue here, but it is worth noting.

I strongly recommend you use Fortran 2003 and ISO_C_BINDING for C-Fortran interoperability.  It was designed for exactly this purpose and works incredibly well relative to the pile of non-portable voodoo required otherwise.

Comment: Hello Jeff ! sorry for the long delay. I cannot give you the whole code because there are to many files (around 700). It is an old code I work on, and it is just impossible for me to upgrade the langage itself. However I found the solution : the user was generating a selfmade piece of code that i was not aware of, and a lot of variables were in conflict. I found the solution just today, by pure "luck" ... (no worries, we found a way around, the issue itself has been solved a while ago)